# What are the most efficient ways to transmit force through air?

Tags: electromagnetism, forces

I am taking part in a robotics competition, where the challenge is to create a pair of robots which successfully navigate a series of obstacles. However, the rules state that of the two robots, only one must have a driving actuator. The other must somehow be moved by the other robot, WITHOUT PHYSICAL CONTACT.

I could think of either having sails on the non-driving robot, and moving it with fans on the driving one OR electromangnets on the driving one and permanent magnets with the opposite polarity on the non-driving one. However the problem with both is that efficiency falls off drastically with distance. Thus, I am looking for possible ways to overcome this problem.

Also, the driving robot has a cable power supply, while the non-driving one may only have batteries which can steer it.

I believe this question belongs to Physics as I want to know the actual forces possible, not their implementation in robots. Thanks :)

Comment: One can't transmit force without physical contact, one can, however, have a false definition of physical contact. Do they mean no baryonic contact? That takes air out of the solution space.

Comment: @CuriousOne I think that the phrase means that the two robots must not touch each other. Also, what do you mean by air?

Comment: Presumably "physical contact" in this case means "direct mechanical contact". Because with a string, one is not touching the other - both are touching the string. Just like when you use the air as a mechanical means - it is just a "very light string". So - is it possible to be clearer about what is and isn't allowed? Is "air" an allowed medium for transmitting the force, or does it actually need to be a field? Also - what is a driving actuator. If you blow against a fan mounted on robot 2, can that move the robot (see "[Strandbeest](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0Tqbym9gzX8)")?

Comment: By the way... "physical contact" is nothing but the electrostatic force over atomic distances at work... so it's fields one way or another. A better definition of the requirement would have been that the physical surfaces of the two units can never come closer than x inches.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you install 1). a laser (say, CO2 laser) - on the driving robot; and 2). a flat object absorbing laser radiation - on the driven robot. The laser radiation can be focused on the object, it will heat the object, the air near the object will be heated, its pressure will increase somewhat, it will move away from the object and produce a force acting on the driven robot. This approach is neither cheap nor safe, but the force does not fall with distance as abruptly as in your approaches.

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to find a way to transmit relatively high forces over a long non-mechanical distance efficiently, then I'd suggest patenting it and ringing some space agencies.

For the mean time, I would stick to transmitting force by moving air. Fans don't reach very far. However, there are more accurate solutions. You could take a look at vortex cannons. All you need is [a box](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4b2SV3ASUxY).

Comment: Even with the sarcasm, the idea of vortex cannons actually appears to be useful. Could you help me with estimating how much more efficient a vortex cannon is compared to a propeller fan?